# Is there any way to inspect the contents of the RocksDB instance used by NEAR Protocol?

Tags: nearprotocol

*Disclosure: I work with NEAR and am currently on-boarding*.

When I start up a local node on a clean machine I see that a `.near` folder is created in my home directory with a few configuration files (exact files seem to depend on which `start_` script I run). Another folder appears inside of the `.near` folder called `data`.

Running `strings ~/.near/data/*.sst` in the folder spits out a few lines starting with the string "rocksdb" which led me to [this reference](https://github.com/nearprotocol/nearcore/blob/master/core/store/src/lib.rs#L12) to [RocksDB](https://rocksdb.org)

Is there any way to inspect the contents of a node's RocksDB instance?

I found [Keylord](https://protonail.com/) but it crashes when I try to configure a new connection to the database (by pointing the connection to `~/.near/data`).  I didn't pursue that thread.

*PSA1: sometimes it's useful to backup the `~/.near` folder between node restarts if you want to reset the environment or avoid reusing old data while troubleshooting*

```
mv ~/.near ~/.near_`date +%Y-%m-%d.%s`
```

*PSA2: on MacOS you can watch what happens to the contents of the `~/.near` folder while the node boots up and runs. (`brew install watch`).*

```
watch -d -c -n 0.5 find ~/.near
```

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/rocksdb/wiki/Administration-and-Data-Access-Tool

Comment: the link to keylord goes to protonail.com, not sure what that's about

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The content of RocksDB is serialized using our own binary serialization format (http://borsh.io/), so you won't be able to examine the content with general-purpose third-party tools