# Unable to read from NEAR's rocksDB

Tags: nearprotocol

I'm trying to iterate through NEAR's RocksDB,
I've downloaded the small backup from s3 and using the code below to iterate through col33 (transactions)
But it doesn't print anything as RocksDB would be empty (but it is not obviously),
could you please  point me out what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks

```
use std::env;
use rocksdb::{ColumnFamilyDescriptor, DB, IteratorMode, Options};

fn col_name(col: i32) -> String {
    format!("col{}", col)
}

fn main() {
    println!("Hello, RocksDB!");
    let args: Vec<String> = env::args().collect();
    let path = if args.len() > 1 {
        args.get(1).unwrap().clone()
    } else {
        String::from("./data")
    };
    println!("data dir={}", &path);

    let opts = Options::default();
    let mut cfs:Vec<ColumnFamilyDescriptor> = Vec::new();
    for col in  33..34 {
        cfs.push(
            rocksdb::ColumnFamilyDescriptor::new(col_name(col),opts.clone()));
    }
    let db = DB::open_cf_descriptors_read_only(
        &opts,&path, cfs, false,
    ).unwrap();

    let iter = db.iterator(IteratorMode::Start);
    for (key, value) in iter {
        println!("Saw {:?} {:?}", key, value);
        let k = String::from_utf8(key.to_vec()).unwrap();
        let v = String::from_utf8(value.to_vec()).unwrap();
        println!("Saw {:?} {:?}", k, v);
    }
    let _ = DB::destroy(&Options::default(), &path);
}
```

Comment: I had the same question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58863524/2836874

Comment: Oh, ok, thanks for that!
But nevertheless, I expect to see at least raw bytes, but it reads nothing.

Comment: Which column family does the data live in? The iteration is over the default column family which might be empty

Comment: Loop over each column family and do the iteration on each column family

Comment: Yeah, I've used wrong iterator, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I've found what was wrong,
as Asad Awadia mentioned, I'm using iterator over default column family here.

I've used **iterator_cf** instead and got some data:

```
    let cf_handle = db.cf_handle("col33").unwrap();
    let iter = db.iterator_cf(cf_handle, IteratorMode::Start);
```